# how to get column values and column count from table in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I want column values and same column count from table in oracle.

Below is the query:

```
select username,
       count(username) 
  from ind_emp_leaves 
 where  status != 'Approved' 
   and  (leavefromdate BETWEEN to_date('08-09-2013','dd/MM/yyyy') 
                           AND to_date('11-09-2013','dd/MM/yyyy')) OR
        (LEAVETODATE  BETWEEN to_date('08-09-2013','dd/MM/yyyy') 
                          AND to_date('11-09-2013','dd/MM/yyyy'))
```

Above query is showing error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Without username field it's displaying count value, but I want both username values and username count also.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please format your code in a readable way (I've done it for you).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the count per user, this should give the correct result:

```
select username, count(*) from ind_emp_leaves 
where  (status != 'Approved') 
  and  ((leavefromdate BETWEEN to_date('08-09-2013','dd/MM/yyyy') 
     AND to_date('11-09-2013','dd/MM/yyyy')) 
  OR (LEAVETODATE  BETWEEN to_date('08-09-2013','dd/MM/yyyy') 
     AND to_date('11-09-2013','dd/MM/yyyy')))
group by username
```

Please note that I put additional parens around the leavedate part - I *assume* you want the "status != 'Approved'" part to be checked for both intervals, not only the first one.

Comment: if i remove additional parens my count showing error, previously my count is 2

Comment: @appu I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say - do you get an error when running my query?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired result by using following code..

```
  select username, count(*) from ind_emp_leaves 
     where  status != 'Approved')
     and  ((leavefromdate BETWEEN to_date('08-09-2013','dd/MM/yyyy') 
     AND to_date('11-09-2013','dd/MM/yyyy')) 
     OR (LEAVETODATE  BETWEEN to_date('08-09-2013','dd/MM/yyyy') 
     AND to_date('11-09-2013','dd/MM/yyyy')))
     group by username
```

Answer (score 0):

hey if you are using aggregate functions like!

```
AVG
COLLECT
CORR
CORR_*
COUNT
COVAR_POP
COVAR_SAMP
CUME_DIST
DENSE_RANK
FIRST
GROUP_ID
GROUPING
GROUPING_ID
LAST
```

you should use group by function!.